# web view opening links in safari with certain keywords

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, hyperlink

I am trying to open certain links in my web view that will be shown in safari. Here is the code I have so far.

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```

Problem is I want to only open up safari if the links contain the keyword "google". Any tips on what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check like this, it will serve the purpose

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
   if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
      if ([[inRequest.URL absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"google" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location!=NSNotFound){
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
         return NO;
       }
    }
 return YES;
}
```

Comment: Cool,and if I wanted the opposite say open all links in safari except keywords with google I switch return values right.

Comment: then take out the  `!` from the check

Comment: if ([[inRequest.URL absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"google"].location==NSNotFound){}

Comment: like so -(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        if ([[inRequest.URL absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"google"].location==NSNotFound){
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}